# ReferenceError: client is not defined. Discord JS

Tags: discord

```
ReferenceError: clinet is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/main.js:34:9)
at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/gavinmartin/Desktop/myshadow/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

This error happens when trying to run a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your code thats causing the error when asking.

Although looking at this `clinet is not defined`

It seems that you misspelled `client` most likely

Comment: `client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'support'){
        client.commands.get('support').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'cmds'){
        client.commands.get('cmds').execute(message, args);
    }
});`

Comment: !ping, !support work but !cmds doesn't and it's formatted the same way.

Comment: @WoahCreates the error is clear, it says `clinet is not defined`. you wrote `clinet` in your code and not `client` at `main.js` line 34 position 9. it seems like you fixed the typo in your comment but that's simply what caused the error in your question so fix it in your code and it'll work